# How to put articles under a /blog directory?

Tags: permalinks, directory, template-hierarchy

I have a homepage, work (as parent pages) and several pages (as child), but when it comes to articles, I can't choose the relation between them and the page Blog.

Resuming, I can choose the hierarchy relation between pages, but I'm in trouble putting the articles under a "directory" called blog.
If change the permalinks, I will change it for all pages and articles, so I'm lost on this.

Note: I have a blog page where there is a list of articles, but instead of www.claro.pt/blog/article - I have www.claro.pt/article

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To use /blog/ as base of your posts you are supposed to use the `Category Base` option in your permalink settings.

[image: Permalink Settings]

Go to Optional and enter "blog" into the `Category Base`

[image: Optional Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to keep you original articles intact but only have /blog for articles that are on your Page named Blog (i.e. You are not using Wordpress's blog home page and not using the usual Wordpress loop).

To achieve what you want, you will need to add your own rewrite rules (via functions.php) for the articles you require and filter the specific permalinks for those articles as well. If you group those articles with a category or tag, it would make it easier to do so.

However, if you rather set /blog for all articles in the whole Wordpress install (which doesn't include pages) permalink settings (or even setting a blog page in reading settings) are much easier solutions